# How can I fix this decode error and make the program work?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to run this code (https://gist.github.com/eknowles/9939273). This code tries to make automatic trading in Steam Market in behalf of me. I have a C background so I thought someone can help me in here. This is a automatci trading bot which should work according to author of the code as you can see below. I am trying make it work. When I try to run it after entering my profileid, sessionid, and cookie and creating objects as the author of the code told below the link I have given above,

```
>>> import botlast

>>> m=botlast.Market()

>>> m.RunSeller()
```

I get below errors. If you help me how to fix these I will be grateful. Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\bottt.py", line 175, in RunSeller
res = json.load(f)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
**kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 365, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: what does `print f` give?

Comment: When I write print f in the console I get this:   >>> print f
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Comment: i meant what happens if you put `print f` right before the line at which the error is thrown? ie bottt.py line, 175

Comment: This : C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Python27/suggestion.py
  File "C:/Python27/suggestion.py", line 176
    res = json.load(f)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the creator of the Gist.
It looks like your profile id is incorrect. Make sure it's the text part.

For example the profile http://steamcommunity.com/id/gabe has the profileid of 'gabe'.
It could be that your session and cookie information is incorrect, the best way to test this is to go to steam and put an item on sale.

Before you do, open up Developer Tools and listen for a GET request.
[image: i.stack.imgur.com/lGsSR.png]

Then copy out all the information in the cookie.
[image: i.stack.imgur.com/Z1sku.jpg]

I've highlighted the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code in question is fetching a URL and trying to load what it returns into a json dict:

```
inventory = self.hosturl+"id/"+self.profileid+"/inventory/json/"+self.appid+"/"+self.contextid
r = requests.post(inventory, '')
req = urllib2.Request(inventory)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(req)
res = json.load(f)
```

Are you sure that valid json is being returned from that url (the url contained in the `inventory` variable)?

**Edit**

Try editing that block of code to actually print out what was returned:

```
inventory = self.hosturl+"id/"+self.profileid+"/inventory/json/"+self.appid+"/"+self.contextid
r = requests.post(inventory, '')
req = urllib2.Request(inventory)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(req)
val = f.read()
print("val is {}".format(val))
res = json.loads(val)
```

Hopefully that provides something useful.

Comment: You know what I do not know if it fetches json object successfully but  In the steam forum there are some people who use this code successfully but give no clue to other people. Most probably I am doing sthg wrong.

Comment: @Lyrk I edited my answer with a change you can make to the code that will show you exactly what's being returned.

Comment: >>> import suggestion   
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "C:\Python27\suggestion.py", line 170
        inventory =         self.hosturl+"id/"+self.profileid+"/inventory/json/"+self.appid+"
                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>>

Comment: dano , while I tried to import it, it gave above error.

Comment: @Lyrk I mean edit the actual source script you're trying to run.

Comment: I changed the code part with the code you gave me. It gives this when  I try to run C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Python27/suggestion.py
  File "C:/Python27/suggestion.py", line 170
    inventory = self.hosturl+"id/"+self.profileid+"/inventory/json/"+self.appid+"
                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: This: `inventory = self.hosturl+"id/"+self.profileid+"/inventory/json/"+self.appid+"/"+self.contextid` is all one line. I fixed my post so it stops getting split into two.

Comment: Yea I did it. But it gives me indention error. Check this link. http://imgur.com/1tQB8PT

Comment: That's very strange. Maybe a tabs vs. spaces issue?

Comment: I corrected that indention error. Like you said. Now I get this: C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Python27/suggestion.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/suggestion.py", line 17, in <module>
    class Market(object):
  File "C:/Python27/suggestion.py", line 175, in Market
    val = f.read()
NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1